# Compiling exe or dll by webserver

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I'd like to compile my source (or a part of it) by one of my webservers (like some websites offer nightly builds of their program). As I want my program to be customized by a third party and they have their own standalone application with say their logo and some custom strings in it. My preferable solution would be a dll file which would be loaded into my application, so I can still update the main application while retaining the customization by the third party.

So, the third party goes to my website, enters some fields and a dll file is generated (or do you have any other *better* way to do this?) and the dll file will be included by the application, which will grab the logo resource and some strings from it, to show in the application.

How can this be done? I'd rather to use Linux to build it, but if Windows is easier then that's not a problem either.

Comment: you want to use a continuous integration software, google for it (CruiseControl, Jenkins, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSharpCodeProvider API for that, here is an example:

```
var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "foo.exe", true);
parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
@"using System.Linq;
    class Program {
      public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var q = from i in Enumerable.Rnge(1,100)
                  where i % 2 == 0
                  select i;
      }
    }");

results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));
```

If you want to use linux take a look at [Mono MCS C# Compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler)

Comment: This would require the compilation to be run at the client, I'd rather do this server side.

Comment: Why does this require the compilation to be run at the client? Do it at the server side then

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I wasn't thinking of ASP.NET. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Well, then what did you mean? :) What kind of server are we talking?

Comment: I wasn't meaning anything specifically, I only build stuff at the server side with PHP, however I now might install a 2008 server and experiment with some ASP.NET to build it ;-)

Comment: Mono has an implementation of ASP.NET you could use it too http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET :)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy on either platform. Just accept the data into a template C# file (String.Replace will work fine). And then just shell out to the compiler.

Comment: Could you eleborate on the C# template file? Is this some text file with some strings in it?

Answer (score 0):

If you trust your third party vendor try to use Team City by JetBrains, commiting some changes in svn repo folder, will cause recompilation of project and you will get precompiled project.

Comment: I'm not sharing the SVN, they don't need to see the code either. Just some strings and a logo.

Comment: In this case I would make a gui page with upload functionality, and made some service tool looking after changes in some folder. Once changes happened just recompile solution with added resources.

Comment: But this will build the whole source, if I just let the user create a dll file, than these two would be independent of eachother, so if I create a new version, each third party doesn't have to rebuild the complete application, instead the program will self-update and the data can still be retrieved from the dll file.

Comment: AFAIK resource files could exist as standalone files, so changes made to this files, doesn't require project recompilation. Haven't tried it, it's just my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

Build a web interface to capture the third party's customisations into, say, a database.

Set up a Continuous Integration server to manage automated builds (for example [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)).

Then implement custom build steps in your CI solution to grab the customisations, drop them into copies of the source code, and have your CI do a build for each client - publishing the build artefacts somewhere where the client can see them (say, somewhere within the web interface)

You could set up custom triggers in your CI server to watch the database for new customisations. Or to be triggered by some operation in the web UI.

Comment: But this will build the whole source, if I just let the user create a dll file, than these two would be independent of eachother, so if I create a new version, each third party doesn't have to rebuild the complete application, instead the program will self-update and the data can still be retrieved from the dll file.

Comment: A CI product will only build the whole source if that's what you tell it to do. You could easily configure it to just compile one assembly with some resources you drag in, combine it with a reference product build (overwriting the DLL, for example), packaging it into an installer, and pushing it back to the web server. The web server is NOT the place to be compiling code.